# Rendering wrongly in screw modifier

Tags: modifiers, screw-modifier

Hi I wanted to create the following structure. I have created a single edge and used screw modifier to create this. I used freestlye option to display the edges. However when I render, I am seeing this extra edges! These are not visible in viewport or camera displays.
How to avoid it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It renders all edges, even the ones that are made by automatic triangulation during rendering. Maybe you marked the faces instead of edges. You should only mark the edges and also set the render settings to render only marked:

[image]